# 'Debug' unformats floppy disk when writing bootloader to first sector

Tags: debugging, assembly, nasm

I am trying to write a very basic operating system in Assembly by following this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MJUGVFAXKg

My code is fine and has all been compiled to .bin files via NASM and, using a virtual machine running Windows XP, I have written the bootloder file to the (virtual) floppy using the 'debug' command, as per the video. This is all successful, and when I boot into the OS, it displays a 'kernel.bin file not found' error, which is expected becasue the kernel file wasn't on the floppy disk.

So I boot back into XP and try to copy the kernel.bin file to the floppy, but Windows tells me that the floppy is not formatted and asks me if I would like to format it. Obviously, once the disk is formatted, it is wiped, so it seems that I cannot have both the bootloader.bin and kernel.bin on the floppy at the same time.

How do I write other files to the disk as well as the bootloader?

You'll have to explain this in very simple terms; I'm an absolute beginner.

Thanks.

Comment: Whether a floppy is "formatted" or not depends on the existance of a "Boot Parameter Block" (there are other names for this structure). If you include this code in your bootsector, you should be able to copy "kernel.bin" to the floppy. If you do this, you will need code to load a "named file" in your bootsector - not so easy! Easier to concatenate the two files and write 'em to the floppy all at once. Then you need code to load a "known sector" (2). I don't mean to discourage you, but "my own OS" is NOT a job for a beginner! osdev.org is your friend...

Comment: This may help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I know that OS development isn't for beginner - just one look at assembly code tells me that - but I thought I'd give it a go anyway, just becasue I'm curious how they work. I'll concatenate the files and take a look at osdev.org and work it out from there. Thanks again.

Comment: I fixed it. I downloaded someone else's bootloader which had a correctly functioning Boot Parameter Block. I must have made a mistake on the code on my own file which was preventing XP from recognising the disk as formatted. So it boots correctly now. Thanks so much for your input: I have definitely learnt something today and have a basic OS to call my own!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I downloaded someone else's bootloader which had a correctly functioning Boot Parameter Block. I must have made a mistake on the code on my own file which was preventing XP from recognising the disk as formatted. So it boots correctly now. Thanks so much for your input, Frank Kotler, I have definitely learnt something today and have a basic OS to call my own!